# Who is Vratya mentioned in the Atharva Veda?

Tags: shiva, atharva-veda

The Atharva Veda Book 15 mentions about Vratya who created this universe and roused Prajapati/Brahma to action. So, is the Vratya described Lord Shiva as 15:1 says he becomes Mahadev Or is it a Supreme  being similar to Purusha or Viraj?

Comment: In general, by Vratya is meant a wandering monk in AV.

Comment: @Rickross can Lord shiva be considered that wandering monk cause  AV 15:1 also that he was red and blue in colour he hold the  Bow of Indra and the word mahadev is used.So this description can be used to describe Lord shiva.

Comment: I am talking generally here not about any particular mantra. I'll check the particular mantras.

Comment: Very Excellent question. By looking at the verses we can say that both the cases are possible. We can see words like  Nila-Lohita etc. which are of lord Shiva .  And some places we can say that its  Virat Purusha. Will try to give answer..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So is the Vratya describe is Lord shiva as 15:1 says he become Mahadeva  Or is it a Supreme being similiar to Purusha or Viraj?

If we look  at **Atharva Veda Kanda 15 – Adhayatma Prakaran Sukta.** We can see  that the Devata of that Sukta is Vratya. . Here its said that after becoming leader of group of Vratyas he advised Prajapati. This Vratya became Lord of the gods , Ishana , Ishwara . He is singularly became the leader of Vratyas.  group  .The back is of red color and  outer central stomach is of blue color.

Here are the verses from Atharva Veda -

> व्रात्य आसीदीयमान एव स प्रजापतिं समैरयत ||1||
>
> Vratya AsiDiYaMaaNa Eva Sa PrajaPatim SamaiRayat
>
> After acquiring Vratya form , Group leader Vratya advised the best
> superior knowledge to Praja Palak Brahma.
>
> ---
>
> तमेकभवत् तल्ललाममभवत् तन्महदभवत् तज्ज्येजष्ठम्भवत् तद् | 
> ब्रह्माभवत् तत् तपोsभवत् तत् सत्यमभवत् तेन प्राजायत ||3||
>
> TamekaBhavat TallaLaMaMaBhavt TanMaHyadBhavt TajjYaiJaShthaBhavat Tad
> BrahmaBhavat Tat TapoBhavat Tat SatyaBhavat Tena PrajaYat
>
> Whom , the Prajapati  became turned great , amazing ,broad (jeshtha)
> ,Brahma (creator) ,became powerful and truthful. From that only one
> this (Vratya) came into existence.
>
> ---
>
> सोsवर्धत स महाभवत् स महादेवोsभवत् ||4||
>
> So Vardhata Sa MahaBhavata sa MahaDevoBhavat
>
> The which whome is Prajapati (Vratya or Rudra –Shiva)  added /created
> progeny (praja)  and by this growth he became very great (Maha)
> –became Mahadeva.
>
> ---
>
> स देवानामीशां पर्येत् स ईशानोsभवत् ||5||
>
> Sa DevaNaMiShaam Paryet sa IshanoBhavat    He Who became revered; as
> Ishwara or Ishana
>
> ---
>
> नीलमस्योदरं लोहितं पृष्ठम् ।|7||
>
> NilaMasyoUdaram Lohitam Prushtham
>
> His back is of red color and outer central portion of stomach is of
> blue color.

We can see here  in this sukta the names like Nila-Lohita which are also stated  in Puranas  which are of Lord Shiva Or Mahadeva Or Rudra.

Here  [**Linga Purana 2.19**](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/linga-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-18/topic-1)  uses name Nila-Lohita  for Lord Rudra.

> नीलश्च लोहितश्चैव प्रधानपुरुषान्वयात् । स्कंदस्ते यतः शुक्ल तथा
> शुक्लमपैति च ।।
>
> He is of both Blue and Red colour since both Pradhana and Purusha
> merge in him. Since the semen flows from him, he is known as Shukla.

This is the puranic verse from [**Shreemad Bhagvat Purana**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/12/15) which is same as verse 4 and 7 - of Atharva veda kanda 15.

> इत्यादिष्ट: स गुरुणा भगवान्नीललोहित: |
>  सत्वकृतिस्वभावेन्
> ससर्जात्मसमा: प्रजा: ||15||
>
> ity ādiṣṭaḥ sva-guruṇā bhagavān nīla-lohitaḥ
>  sattvākṛti-svabhāvena
> sasarjātma-samāḥ prajāḥ
>
> The most powerful Rudra, whose bodily color was blue mixed with red,
> created many offspring exactly resembling him in features, strength
> and furious nature.

Here Rudra Or Shiva is said to be of Blue-Red color , this verse is clearly of Rudra Or Shiva.

> **Conclusion** – So from carefully looking at the adjacent  verse Of Athrva-Veda and the veres from puranas ,we can say that here most
> probably the deity Vratya  from Atharva veda is Lord Shiva Or Rudra Or
> Maha Deva. We can clearly see the resemblance of the terms used in
> both vedas and Puranas. Here  Vratya is also depicted a supreme
> Ishwara. But  he is not stated as Supreme being similiar to Purusha or
> Viraj ,at least  in this sukta of Atharvaveda.

Comment: Good answer. I think seed of creation is more accurate than semen. Sanskrit is based on properties rather than objects.

Comment: Also follow this proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language

Comment: But the last hymns of this chapter attribute to Indra being Vratya, any explanation on that? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

There are 18 Paryayas (sub-chapters) in the 15th chapter of AtharvaVeda. All the paryayas describe the activity of Vratya. So, in general consideration the Devata of whole chapter is Vratya.

But if we look in the [5th paryaya](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av15005.htm) of 15th chapter, the Devata there is mentioned as Lord Rudra:
[image]
So, it is clear that Vratya described in AtharvaVeda is Lord Shiva himself. The reason why Devata of other paryaya is written Vratya and why Devata of 5th paryaya is written Rudra is because 5th parayaya is strongly associated with Ashta-Murti form of Shiva. Although the 5th chapter describes the activity of Vratya but it is in relation with Ashta-Murti form of Shiva.

> **Bhava** the Archer, a deliverer, delivers him from the intermediate space of the eastern region..... **Sarva** the Archer his deliverer from the intermediate space of the southern region......  **Pasupati** the Archer his deliverer from the intermediate space of the western region...... They made **Rudra** the Archer his deliverer from the intermediate space of the region of the nadir...... **Mahādeva** his deliverer from the intermediate space of the region of the zenith..... **Ishana** the Archer,  a deliverer, delivers him from all the intermediate regions. (AtharvaVeda 15.5)

Also in the 1st paraya or Birth of the Vratya section, the Devata of 5th Mantra which states 'Vratya became Ishana.', is Rudra.
[image]

> स देवानामीशां पर्यैत्स ईशानोऽभवत् ।। 5
>    He gained the lordship of the Gods. He became Ishana.

Also without looking the Devata also, by the description of birth given in 1st Paryaya, it is clearly known it is Lord Shiva who is described there:

> व्रात्य आसीदीयमान एव स प्रजापतिं समैरयत् ।।
>   स प्रजापति: सुवर्णमात्मन्नपश्यत्तत्प्राजनयत् ।।
>   तदेकमभवत्तल्ललाममभवत्तन्महदभवत्तज्जेष्ठमभवत्तद्ब्रह्माभवत्तत्तपोऽभवत्तत्सत्यमभवत्तेन प्राजायत ।।
>   सोऽवर्धत स महानभवत्स महादेवोऽभवत् ।।
>   स देवानामीशां पर्यैत्स ईशानोऽभवत् ।।
>   स एकव्रात्योऽभवत्स धनुरादत्त तदेवेन्द्रधनुः ।।
>   नीलमस्योदरं लोहितं पृष्ठम् ।।
>   नीलेनैवाप्रियं भ्रातृव्यं प्रोर्णोति लोहितेन द्विषन्तं विध्यतीति  ब्रह्मवादिनो वदन्ति ।।  [Atharva Veda 15:1]
>   
>   There was Vratya . He roused Prajapati to action. **Prajapati** beheld gold in himself and **engendered it.** That became unique, that became distinguished, that became great, that became excellent, that became Brahman, that became Tapas, that became Truth: **through that he (Vratya) was born.** He grew, he became great, **he became Mahadeva.** He gained the lordship of the Gods. **He became Ishana.** He became Eka Vratya. He held a bow, even that Bow of Indra. **His belly is dark-blue, his back is red (Nila Lohitam).** With dark-blue he envelops a detested rival, with red he pierces the man who hates him: so the knowers of Brahman say.

NilaLohita term in Vedas is used to denote Lord Shiva as I [discuss here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/why-is-lord-shiva-called-nilalohita) Also the names Mahadeva and Ishana are used to denote Lord Shiva as I [discuss here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/what-names-of-lord-shiva-used-today-are-from-vedas/13650#13650)

So, Vratya described in 15th chapter of AtharvaVeda is Lord Shiva.

Comment: I have my own doubts. If Vraatya is Bhagwan Shiv then from puranic accounts where does it say He has a mistress(lover) who is Usha and Ira ? From this link - http://sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av15002.htm keyword here is Leman which means mistress. So there is no relation between Rudra of the puranas who is eka patni vrata and this person.

Comment: @gansub It is just a symbolic representation not literal.usha repersents dawn which is consort of surya. So in Shri rudram it is stated that surya(sun)is Rudra s form.Rudra is also stated as Sun in Rigveda symbolically so Dawn represents her consort and so is case with Ira.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda How do you know it is symbolic and not literal ? First of all I do not think Vraatya is Rudra. Vraatya could be Sri Krishna and Usha could be Radha Raani. Why not this train of thought ?

Comment: @gansub first of all Lord krishna is nowhere mentioned in vedas and Radha raani?she ist mentioned even in mahabharata,she is mentioned in brahma vavarta puran which is filled with interpolations and if they wanted to mention krishna and radha why didt they mention it directly anywhere?see krishna is not mentioned in vedas because he was born thousand years later  then the composition of vedas and vedas dont predict future and I dont have this train of thought beacuse diety of hymn 5 is Rudra which is shiva only.Kindly see above answer and see Rickross s answer too.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda I have read the original sanskrit text in the Atharva Veda and the word is Pumschali and Usha is described as pumschali - http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=pumzcali&direct=au&anz=100. So that is NOT a consort. Nobody would describe a wife as a pumschali. So Vraatya is a mixed deity like Ayappa or Venkateshara or Sri Krishna

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda In the Vishnu sahasranaama Maahadeva is one of the names of Vishnu

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ira_(name) is also one of the names of Saraswati. So in the Saraswati Sahasranaama Saraswati is described as pleasure giver of Janaardaana.  Come to your own conclusions. The word is Janaardana priyakaree -http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=priyakara&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3

Comment: @gansub come to your own conclusions?which conclusions that say The diety of hymn is Rudra?this is mentioned in atharva veda itself by disagreeing to this one would contradict vedic statements.So if the diety is Rudra then what is the problem In believing that it is dedicated to lord shiva and oh please dont talk about vishnu sasharam,this has now become old.Mahadeva is also name of lord shiva in shiva sahasranama and please see vedas as it is.Rudra suktas cannot be dedicated to Vishnu and vishnu suktas cannot be dedicated to shiva.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda You are digging a larger hole. There are two deities in that hymn. One is Adhyaatma Vraatya and the fifth one is dedicated to Rudra. So I am quoting from the Sanskrit text. So Rudra and Mahaadeva are names common to both Vishnu and Shiva. How are you going to say unequivocally they are not ? So if you want to continue this conversation quote from the Sanskrit text not the English translation.