# Is there any dhyana shloka which mentions Lord Shiva's colour as shyam?

Tags: shiva

At many places, Shiva's colour is mentioned white as karpoor or silver.

But, there are many images of Lord Shiva where he is depicted in same colour as of Lord Vishnu.

So, is there any dhyana shloka which mentions Lord Shiva's colour as shyam?

Comment: [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8973/3869)  says the colour of Shiva is white.@YDS

Comment: I m already aware of this answer and other references.. u can conclude that from first line of Q "At many places, Shiva's colour is mentioned white as karpoor or silver.".. @srimannarayanakv

Comment: It seems in pictures he is shown in shyam colour bcz he applies bhashma all over his body  or there r other forms of Shiva whith shyam color..