# Why Rudra was described as a physician or a surgeon as per Vedas?

Tags: vedas, shiva, yajur-veda

As per Shiva purana, we know that how Shiva had cured chandra & fixed the head of goat and elephant in the case of daksha & ganesh. But why Rudra was described as a physician, surgeon or the god of health. Is it true as per Yajurveda that Rudra had cured the Sun, when he lost his brightness?

Comment: There are mantras of others gods too for good health...and Ashvin gods, Dhanvantri are also mentioned as physician, sirgeon...so ur title Q and initial Qs in body are opinion based...if u want to ask last question mentioned in body, pls edit the title accordingly..

Comment: Mahamrityujna mantra is not for Good health but it is for Vedic immortality  Which stands for Liberation or Moskha to say.See this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21632/11510 The answer explains the meaning.

Comment: Good question@aniket kumar singh

Answer (score 7):

### Why Rudra was described as a physician, surgeon or the god of health?

Lord Shiva's hand is filled with [sovran medicines](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/how-is-lord-shiva-revealed-in-the-rig-veda/17950#17950), hence it is natural that Parameswara will be asked to cure all types of ailments also:

> हस्ते विभ्रद् भेषजा (RigVeda 1.114.5) 
>  
> **whose hand filled of sovran medicines.**

So, Rishis in RigVeda also say:

> भिषक्तमं त्वा भिषजां शृणोमी (RigVeda 2.33.4)
>
> **I hear you as the most curing among all curing.** 
>  
> क्व से ते रुद्र मृडयाकुर हस्तो (RigVeda 2.33.7)
>
> **where is that gracious Hand of thine Lord Rudra?**

### Is it true as per Yajurveda that Rudra had cured the Sun, when he lost his brightness?

Yes, it is true. The most Auspicious [Soma-Rudra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50582/why-is-lord-shiva-called-soma/50583#50583) form was invoked to cure and brightness of the Sun was restored, which I discuss [here also](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/47991/what-is-the-story-of-parvati-closing-the-eyes-of-shiva/47992#47992):

> असाव् आदित्यो न व्यरोचत तस्मै देवाः प्रायश्चित्तिम् ऐच्छन् तस्मा एतꣳ सोमारौद्रं चरुं निर् अवपन् तेनैवास्मिन् रुचम् अदधुः । यो ब्रह्मवर्चसकामः स्यात् तस्मा एतꣳ सोमारौद्रं चरुं निर् वपेत् सोमं चैव रुद्रं च स्वेन भागधेयेनोप धावति ताव् एवास्मिन् ब्रह्मवर्चसं धत्तो ब्रह्मवर्चस्य् एव भवति (Yajurveda 2.2.5)
> **Yonder sun did not shine**, the gods sought an atonement for him, for him they offered this **oblation to Soma-Rudra**: verily thereby **they bestowed brightness upon him.** If he desires to become resplendent, he should offer for him this oblation to Soma and Rudra; verily he has recourse to Soma and Rudra with their own portion; verily they bestow upon him splendour; he becomes resplendent.