# What is the story of Parvati closing the eyes of Shiva?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, shiva, puranas, parvati

There is a story in our scriptures where Goddess Parvati closes the eyes of Lord Shiva and the entire Universe went dark due to it. Lord Shiva has been described as [Tryambakam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/i-want-to-know-the-exact-explanation-of-maha-mrityunjaya-mantra/18185#18185) (one with three eyes) in the Vedas. Linga Purana mentions that three eyes of Lord Shiva represents Soma, Surya and Agni!

> तथा सोमस्य सूर्यस्य वह्नेरग्नित्रयस्य च । (Linga Purana 2.54) 
> **The three eyes represent Soma, Surya, and Agni**

Similarly, [Shiva Rahasya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/808/why-does-lord-shiva-have-three-eyes/18919#18919) too states:

> O you who are at peace! Reality or Truth is Eternally One, without a doubt. Yet in order to manifest Its Eternal Glory, Truth creates the various Worlds out of Itself. Therefore It exists in different States or Forms. They are: Spirit, which is like unto Fire; Energy, which is like unto the Sun; and Matter which is like unto the Moon. The Lord was wearing a tiger skin, holding in His mighty hands a blazing trident and a drum, and having the Sun, Moon, and Fire as three eyes.

In such a case Shakti herself covering the eyes of Shiva can have a significant effect in the creation. What is the story of Parvati covering the eyes of Lord Shiva?

- Did this event happen several times?
- Did Parvati close two eyes only or all the three eyes also?
- What were the results of the event after the incident?
- How much time did she close the eyes of Lord?
- How many years passed on earth and other planets during that time (like time dilation)?
- What does the event show?
- Why did such an event happen?

Comment: as per local temple legend books, Kanchi Kamakshi, Madurai Meenakshi, Kashi Visalakshi are also associated with this story...

Comment: @YDS Not sure about other temples but Kanchi relation with this is mentioned in Skandha Purana also...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the event where Parvati closed eyes of Lord Shiva took place several times. Devi [manifests](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/wouldnt-most-of-the-incarnations-of-devi-be-of-sati-not-parvati/14868#14868) in her various forms in various times and plays with Lord Shiva.

In the Taittariya Samhita of the Yajurveda 2.2.5, a story is given where the Sun suddenly loses its brightness and darkness spreads. Then the Gods pray to the deities Soma-Rudra and by the grace of them the light of the sun is restored. The story is as:

> असाव् आदित्यो न व्यरोचत तस्मै देवाः प्रायश्चित्तिम् ऐच्छन् तस्मा एतꣳ सोमारौद्रं चरुं निर् अवपन् तेनैवास्मिन् रुचम् अदधुः । यो ब्रह्मवर्चसकामः स्यात् तस्मा एतꣳ सोमारौद्रं चरुं निर् वपेत् सोमं चैव रुद्रं च स्वेन भागधेयेनोप धावति ताव् एवास्मिन् ब्रह्मवर्चसं धत्तो ब्रह्मवर्चस्य् एव भवति (Yajurveda 2.2.5)
> **Yonder sun did not shine, the gods sought an atonement for him, for him they offered this oblation to Soma and Rudra: verily thereby they bestowed brightness upon him.** If he desires to become resplendent, he should offer for him this oblation to Soma and Rudra; verily he has recourse to Soma and Rudra with their own portion; verily they bestow upon him splendour; he becomes resplendent.

This Vedic Truth manifests in the Universe several times which are described and recorded in the Itihasas and Puranas. In the story of Itihasas and Puranas it is the play of Uma and Rudra which is also called as 'Soma Rudra' or 'Sa Uma Rudra' ie, Rudra who is with Uma.

#### - Parvati closing two eyes of Shiva:

In the [Anushasana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b105.htm) of Mahabharata, we come upon an interesting story where Uma (Parvati) closes the two eyes of Shiva, entire universe goes dark, the Homas and Vashatkaras were stopped and finally Mahadeva saves the Universe by opening his third eye. The story is as:

> ततः स्मयन्ती पाणिभ्यां नर्मार्थं चारुदर्शना |
> हरनेत्रे शुभे देवी सहसा सा समावृणोत् ||२६||
> संवृताभ्यां तु नेत्राभ्यां तमोभूतमचेतनम् |
> निर्होमं निर्वषट्कारं तत्सदः सहसाभवत् ||२७||
> जनश्च विमनाः सर्वो भयत्राससमन्वितः |
> निमीलिते भूतपतौ नष्टसूर्य इवाभवत् ||२८||
> ततो वितिमिरो लोकः क्षणेन समपद्यत |
> ज्वाला च महती दीप्ता ललाटात्तस्य निःसृता ||२९||
> तृतीयं चास्य सम्भूतं नेत्रमादित्यसंनिभम् |
> युगान्तसदृशं दीप्तं येनासौ मथितो गिरिः ||३०||
> ततो गिरिसुता दृष्ट्वा दीप्ताग्निसदृशेक्षणम् |
> हरं प्रणम्य शिरसा ददर्शायतलोचना ||३१||
> दह्यमाने वने तस्मिन्सशालसरलद्रुमे |
> सचन्दनवने रम्ये दिव्यौषधिविदीपिते ||३२||
> मृगयूथैर्द्रुतैर्भीतैर्हरपार्श्वमुपागतैः |
> शरणं चाप्यविन्दद्भिस्तत्सदः सङ्कुलं बभौ ||३३||
> ततो नभःस्पृशज्वालो विद्युल्लोलार्चिरुज्ज्वलः |
> द्वादशादित्यसदृशो युगान्ताग्निरिवापरः ||३४||
> क्षणेन तेन दग्धः स हिमवानभवन्नगः |
> सधातुशिखराभोगो दीनदग्धवनौषधिः ||३५||
> तं दृष्ट्वा मथितं शैलं शैलराजसुता ततः |
> भगवन्तं प्रपन्ना सा साञ्जलिप्रग्रहा स्थिता ||३६||
> उमां शर्वस्तदा दृष्ट्वा स्त्रीभावागतमार्दवाम् |
> पितुर्दैन्यमनिच्छन्तीं प्रीत्यापश्यत्ततो गिरिम् ||३७||
> ततोऽभवत्पुनः सर्वः प्रकृतिस्थः सुदर्शनः |
> प्रहृष्टविहगश्चैव प्रपुष्पितवनद्रुमः ||३८||
> प्रकृतिस्थं गिरिं दृष्ट्वा प्रीता देवी महेश्वरम् |
> उवाच सर्वभूतानां पतिं पतिमनिन्दिता ||३९||
> भगवन्सर्वभूतेश शूलपाणे महाव्रत |
> संशयो मे महाञ्जातस्तं मे व्याख्यातुमर्हसि ||४०||
> किमर्थं ते ललाटे वै तृतीयं नेत्रमुत्थितम् |
> किमर्थं च गिरिर्दग्धः सपक्षिगणकाननः ||४१||
> किमर्थं च पुनर्देव प्रकृतिस्थः क्षणात्कृतः |
> तथैव द्रुमसञ्छन्नः कृतोऽयं ते महेश्वर ||४२||
> महेश्वर उवाच||
> नेत्रे मे संवृते देवि त्वया बाल्यादनिन्दिते |
> नष्टालोकस्ततो लोकः क्षणेन समपद्यत ||४३||
> नष्टादित्ये तथा लोके तमोभूते नगात्मजे |
> तृतीयं लोचनं दीप्तं सृष्टं ते रक्षता प्रजाः ||४४||
> तस्य चाक्ष्णो महत्तेजो येनायं मथितो गिरिः |
> त्वत्प्रियार्थं च मे देवि प्रकृतिस्थः क्षणात्कृतः ||४५|| 
> She who loved to reside on the breast of Himavat advanced in this guise towards her great lord. **The beautiful Uma, with smiling lips and desirous of playing a jest, covered from behind, with her two beautiful hands, the eyes of Mahadeva. As soon as Mahadeva's eyes were thus covered, all the regions became dark and life seemed to be extinct everywhere in the universe.** The Homa rites ceased. The universe became suddenly deprived of the sacred Vashat also. All living creatures became cheerless and filled with fear. Indeed, when the eyes of the lord of all creatures were thus closed, the universe seemed to become sunless. Soon, however, that overspreading darkness disappeared. **A mighty and blazing flame of fire emanated from Mahadeva's forehead. A third eye, resembling another sun, appeared (on it). That eye began to blaze forth like the Yuga-fire and began to consume that mountain.** The large-eyed daughter of Himavat, beholding what occurred, bowed her head unto Mahadeva endued with that third eye which resembled a blazing fire. She stood there with gaze fixed on her lord. When the mountain forests burned on every side, with their Was and other trees of straight Trunks, and their delightful sandals and diverse excellent medicinal herbs, herds of deer and other animals, filled with fright, came with great speed to the place where Hara sat and sought his protection. With those creatures almost filling it, the retreat of the great deity blazed forth with a kind of peculiar beauty. **Meanwhile, that fire, swelling wildly, soared up to the very heavens and endued with the splendor and unsteadiness of lightning and looking like a dozen suns in might and effulgence, covered every side like the all-destroying Yuga-fire. In a moment, the Himavat mountains were consumed, with their minerals and summits and blazing herbs.** Beholding Himavat crushed and consumed, the daughter of that prince of mountains sought the protection of the great deity and stood before him her hands joined in reverence. Then Sarva, seeing Uma overcome by an accession of womanly mildness and finding that she was unwilling to behold her father Himavat reduced to that pitiable plight, cast benignant looks upon the mountain. In a moment the whole of Himavat was restored to his former condition and became as beautiful to look at as ever. Indeed, the mountain put forth a cheerful aspect. All its trees became adorned with flowers. Beholding Himavat to his natural condition, the goddess Uma, divested of every fault, addressed her lord, that master of all creatures, the divine Maheswara, in these words.' "Uma said, 'O holy one, O lord of all creatures, O deity that art armed with the trident, O thou of high vows, a great doubt has filled my mind. It behoveth thee to resolve that doubt for me. **For what reason has this third eye appeared in thy forehead?** Why also was the mountain consumed with the woods and all that belonged to it? Why also, O illustrious deity, hast thou restored the mountain to its former condition? Indeed, having burnt it once, why hast thou again caused it to be covered with trees?' "Maheswara said, 'O goddess without any fault, **in consequence of thy having covered my eyes through an act of indiscretion the universe became in a moment devoid of light. When the universe became sunless and, therefore, all became dark, O daughter of the prince of mountains, I created the third eye desirous of protecting all creatures.** The high energy of that eye crushed and consumed this 'mountain. For pleasing thee, however, O goddess, I once more made Himavat what he was by repairing the injury.'

Here, we can clearly see all the five functions of Shiva-Shakti which are: Shristi, Sthithi, Samhara, Tirodhana, and Anugraham (Creation, Protection, Destruction, Veiling and Gracing) by the activities like recreating the Himavat mountain, protecting the Universe by opening his third eye, putting all creatures in darkness for sometime and again gracing them with light.

#### - Andhaka born due to closing of eyes:

The Shiva Purana (Rudra Samhita Yuddha Khanda) mentions a story where Parvati playfully closes the eyes of Lord Shiva and again the darkness spreads around the world but this time a child called Andhaka (darkness personified) was born. After seeing the fearful child when Parvati again removes the hand the light again spreads:

> पूर्वे दिशो मन्दर शैलसंस्था कपर्द्दिनश्चंडपराकमस्य ।
> चक्रे ततो नेत्रनिमीलनं तु सा पार्वती नर्मयुतं सलीलम् ॥ १६ ॥
> प्रवालहेमाब्जधृतप्रभाभ्यां कराम्बुजाभ्यां निमिमील नेत्रे।।
> हरस्य नेत्रेषु निमीलितेषु क्षणेन जातः सुमहांधकारः।।१७।।
> तत्स्पर्शयोगाच्च महेश्वरस्य करौ च तस्याः स्खलितं मदांभः।।
> शंभोर्ललाटे क्षणवह्नितप्तो विनिर्गतो भूरिजलस्य बिन्दुः।।१८।।
> गर्भो बभूवाथ करालवक्त्रो भयंकरः क्रोधपरः कृतघ्नः।।
> अन्धो विरूपी जटिलश्च कृष्णो नरेतरो वैकृतिकस्सुरोमा।।१९।। गायन्हसन्प्ररुदन्नृत्यमानो विलेलिहानो घरघोरघोषः।।
> जातेन तेनाद्भुतदर्शनेन गौरीं भवोऽसौ स्मितपूर्वमाह।।।।
> श्रीमहेश उवाच।।
> निमील्य नेत्राणि कृतं च कर्म बिभेषि साऽस्माद्दयिते कथं त्वम् ।।
> गौरी हरात्तद्वचनं निशम्य विहस्यमाना प्रमुमोच नेत्रे ।।२१।।
> जाते प्रकाशे सति घोररूपो जातोंधकारादपि नेत्रहीनः ।।
> तादृग्विधं तं च निरीक्ष्य भूतं पप्रच्छ गौरी पुरुषं महेशम् ।। २२ ।।
> गौर्य्युवाच ।।
> कोयं विरूपो भगवन्हि जातो नावग्रतो घोरभयंकरश्च ।।
> वदस्व सत्यं मम किं निमित्तं सृष्टोऽथ वा केन च कस्य पुत्रः ।। २३ ।।
> सनत्कुमार उवाच ।।
> श्रुत्वा हरस्तद्वचनं प्रियाया लीलाकरस्सृष्टिकृतोंऽधरूपाम् ।।
> लीलाकरायास्त्रिजगज्जनन्या विहस्य किंचिद्भगवानुवाच ।।२४।।
> महेश उवाच ।।
> शृण्वंबिके ह्यद्भुतवृत्तकारे उत्पन्न एषोऽद्भुतचण्डवीर्यः ।।
> निमीलिते चक्षुषि मे भवत्या स स्वेदजो मेंधकनामधेयः ।।२५।।
> त्वं चास्य कर्तास्ययथानुरूपं त्वया ससख्या दयया गणेभ्यः ।।
> स रक्षितव्यस्त्वयि तं हि वैकं विचार्य बुद्ध्या करणीयमार्ये ।। २६ ।। (Yuddha Khanda chapter 42) 
>  
> While sporting on the eastern ridges of the Mandara mountain, **Parvati
> sportively and playfully closed the eyes of Siva** of fierce exploit.
> She closed the eyes with her lotus-like hands which had the lustre of coral and
> golden lotus. **When Siva's eyes were closed, a great darkness spread immediately.**
> By this contact with lord Siva the **rapturous rutting juice exuded from her
> hands became hot by the fire of the eye on his forehead and flowed out in copious
> drops. Conception took place and a terrible inhuman being manifested itself**. It was
> furious, ungrateful, blind, deformed, and black in colour. It had matted locks
> of hair and fine hair all over the body.
> It sang, cried, laughed, danced, put out its tongue like a serpent and
> thundered fiercely. When this curious creature arose, Siva smilingly spoke to
> Parvati.
> Lord Siva said:--
> "You did it yourself by closing my eyes. O my beloved, why are you afraid of it
> now? On hearing these words of Siva, **Parvati smilingly took off her hands from the
> eyes.
> When light spread everywhere the blind being appeared even more terrible.** On
> seeing such a being, Parvati asked her lord Siva.
> Parvati said:--
> O lord, what is this ugly hideous being that is born in front of us. Please
> tell me the truth. Why was it created? By whom? Whose child is it?
> Sanatkumara said:--
> On hearing these words of his beloved, the sportively inclined mother of the
> three worlds and the cause of creation of the blind creatures, lord Siva himself
> indulging in sports smilingly said:--
> Lord Siva said:--
> O Parvati of mysterious activities, listen. When my eyes were closed by you,
> this being of wonderfully fierce might was born of my sweat. He shall be named Andhaka.You are the cause of his creation though not in the natural way. He shall be
> guarded by the Ganas lovingly as well as by you along with your friends. His well
> being rests with you. O noble lady, pondering over this intelligently you shall do
> every thing.

Thus this time also Parvati playfully closes eyes of Lord Shiva and great darkness (Maha Andhakara) spreads and due to heat from his third eye juice began to flow from hands of Parvati and a terrible being called Andhaka manifests there.

#### - Parvati closing all three eyes of Shiva:

In the above two incidents we see that Parvati only closes the two eyes of Shiva and Lord Shiva protected the world with his third eye. But in one incident which is described in Skandha Purana, Devi Parvati closes all three eyes of Shiva. The condition here is more dreadful then the previous state as Prakriti itself begins to reach in the Avyakta Rupa (Unmanifested state).

> रतिरूपां शिवां देवीं सर्वसौभाग्यसुन्दरीम् ।।
> कदाचिद्रहसि प्रीता निजाज्ञावशवर्त्तिनम् ।। २३ ।।
> रमणं जानती मुग्धा पश्चादभ्येत्य सादरम् ।।
> कराभ्यां कमलाभाभ्यां त्रिणेत्राणि जगद्गुरोः ।। २४ ।।
> पिदधे लीलया शंभोः किमेतदिति कौतुकात् ।।
> चन्द्रादित्याग्निरूपेण पिहितेष्वक्षिषु क्रमात् ।। २५ ।।
> अन्धकारोऽभवत्तत्र चिरकालं भयंकरः ।।
> निमिषार्द्धेन देवस्य जग्मुर्वत्सरकोटयः ।। २६ ।।
> देवीलीलासमुत्थेन तमसाभूज्जगत्क्षयः ।।
> तमसा पूरितं विश्वमपारेण समन्ततः ।।२७।।
> शून्यं ज्योतिः प्रचारेण विनाशं प्रत्यपद्यत ।।
> न व्यजृंभत विबुधा न च वेदाश्चकाशिरे ।।२८।।
> नापि जीवाः समभवन्नव्यक्तं केवलं स्थितम् ।।
> जगतामपि सर्वेषामकाले वीक्ष्य संक्षयम् ।।२९।।
> तपसा लब्धस्फूर्तीनां विचारः समपद्यत ।।
> किमेतत्तमसो जन्म भुवनक्षयकारणम् ।। 1.3.1.3.३० ।।
> भगवानपि सर्वात्मा न नूनं कालमाक्षिपत् ।।
> देवी विनोदरूपेण पिधत्ते पुरजिद्दृशः ।। ३१ ।।
> तेनेदमखिलं जातं निस्तेजो भुवनत्रयम् ।।
> अकालतमसा व्याप्ते सकले भुवनत्रये ।। ३२ ।।
> का गतिर्लब्धराज्यानां तपसो देवजन्मनाम् ।।
> न यज्ञाः संप्रवर्तंते न पूज्यन्ते सुरा भुवि ।। ३३ ।।
> इति निश्चित्य मनसा वीक्ष्य ते ज्ञानचक्षुषा ।।
> नित्यास्ते सूरयो भक्त्या शंभुमागम्य तुष्टुवुः ।। ३४ ।।
> नमः सर्वजगत्कर्त्रे शिवाय परमात्मने ।।
> मायया शक्तिरूपेण पृथग्भावमुपेयुषे ।। ३५ ।।
> अविनाभाविनी शक्तिराद्यैका शिवरूपिणी ।।
> लीलया जगदुत्पत्तिरक्षासंहृतिकारिणी ।। ३६ ।।
> अर्धांगी सा तव देव शिवशक्त्यात्मकं वपुः ।।
> एक एव महादेवो न परे त्वद्विना विभो ।। ३७ ।।
> लीलया तव लोकोयमकाले प्रलयं गतः ।।
> करुणा तव निर्व्याजा वर्द्धतां लोकवर्द्धनी ।। ३८ ।।
> भवतो निमिषार्द्धेन तेजसामुपसंहृतेः ।।
> गतान्यनेकवर्षाणि जगतां नाशहेतवे ।। ३९ ।।
> ततः प्रसीद करुणामूर्त्ते काल सदाशिव ।।
> विरम प्रणयारब्धादमुष्माल्लोकसंक्षयात् ।। ४० ।।
> इति तेषां वचः श्रुत्वा भक्तानां सिद्धिशालिनाम् ।।
> विसृजाक्षोणि गौरीति करुणामूर्त्तिरब्रवीत् ।। ४१ ।।
> विससर्ज च सा देवी पिधानं हरचक्षुषाम् ।।
> सोमसूर्याग्निरूपाणां प्रकाशमभवज्जगत् ।। ४२ ।।
> कियान्कालो गतश्चेति पृष्टैः सिद्धैश्च वै नतैः ।।
> उक्तं त्वन्निमिषार्द्धेन जग्मुर्वत्सरकोटयः ।। ४३ ।।(Arunachala Khanda chapter 3)
> The delighted goddess (like) a young girl of youthful simplicity, once
> thought her lover to be under her absolute control. So once, she went stealthily
> behind him. With her hands of lotus-like (tenderness and lustre) **she sportingly
> closed the three eyes of Sambhu**, the sire of the world, just out of curiosity to
> know what it was.
> **When the eyes in the forms of the moon, the sun and the fire respectively were closed, there appeared a terrible darkness of a very long duration. With half a
> moment of the Lord crores of (human) years passed by.** The universe came to its
> destruction on account of the darkness caused by the playful sport of the goddess.
> The universe was filled all over with boundless darkness. Being deprived of the
> movement of the luminaries, the universe met with its destruction.
> Devas did not flourish nor did the Vedas shine. No living beings existed.
> Only the Unmanifest (i.e. Prakrti) remained by itself.
> On seeing this untimely destruction of the worlds, it occurred to those (venerable
> persons) who through their penance had gained a flash of inspiration in their
> minds: '(What) is the source of this darkness causing destruction of the worlds.
> Certainly, the Lord, the immanent soul of everyone, has not impelled the god of
> Death. **Playfully the goddess has closed the eyes of the conqueror of Tripura.
> Therefore, the entire unit of the three worlds has become deprived of light.** If the
> three worlds have been pervaded by untimely darkness, what course is left to those
> of divine origin (i.e. gods) who have acquired their realms by means of penance?
> Yajnas are not being performed on the earth. Suras are not being worshipped.'
> On determining this by their mental powers and observing this through their
> vision born of knowledge, those eternal Suris (i.e. persons of spiritual wisdom)
> devoutly bowed down to Sambhu and prayed: "Obeisance to Siva, the Supreme Soul, the maker of the entire universe, who has
> assumed separate forms in the nature of Saktis through Maya. **The inevitable one primordial Sakti in the form of Siva is the cause of
> creation, sustenance and annihilation in a sportful manner.**
> She is half of your body, O Lord, Your body is in the form of Siva and Sakti.
> Mahadeva is one and only one (without a second). O Lord, without you none else
> exists. Thanks to your sporting activity, this world has met with untimely destruction.
> May your genuine mercifulness making the worlds flourish, increase.
> Due to the withdrawal of lights for the duration of half a winking of yours,
> **innumerable years of the worlds have gone by causing their destruction.**
> Therefore, be pleased, O Sadasiva, the embodiment of mercifulness; O Kala (i.e.
> god of Death), stop this destruction of the worlds initiated through love's sport."
> **On hearing these words of those devotees endowed with Siddhis the Lord, the
> embodiment of mercifulness, said, "O Gauri, leave off my eyes."**
> The goddess desisted from continuing the closure of the eyes of Hara in the
> form of the moon, the sun and the fire. **The universe became bright and brilliant.
> On being asked "How much time has passed?", Siddhas bowed down and said, "Along
> with your half a winking crores of (human) years have elapsed."**

In this case, Lord Shiva says to Parvati that it is not suitable for the Mother of the Universe to cause untimely pralaya like this and Parvati desires to do penance for causing the event.

### Key Points:

#### - [Leela](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16182/what-exactly-is-a-leela-%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE-is-there-a-scriptural-definition-of-leela-%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE/16188#16188) (play) of Shiva Shakti:

> हरनेत्रे शुभे देवी सहसा सा समावृणोत् || (Mahabharata)
>  The beautiful Uma, with smiling lips and desirous of playing a jest, covered from behind, with her two beautiful hands, the eyes of Mahadeva. 
> चक्रे ततो नेत्रनिमीलनं तु सा पार्वती नर्मयुतं सलीलम् ॥ (Shiva Purana)
>  Parvati sportively and playfully closed the eyes of Siva. 
> देवी विनोदरूपेण पिधत्ते पुरजिद्दृशः ।। (Skandha Purana)
>  Playfully the goddess has closed the eyes of the conqueror of Tripura. 
> लीलया जगदुत्पत्तिरक्षासंहृतिकारिणी ।। (Skandha Purana)
>  the cause of creation, sustenance, and annihilation in a sportful manner. 
>  देवीलीलासमुत्थेन तमसाभूज्जगत्क्षयः ।।(Skandha Purana) 
>  The universe came to its destruction on account of the darkness caused by the playful sport of the goddess.

#### - The Great Darkness (Maha Andhakara):

> हरस्य नेत्रेषु निमीलितेषु क्षणेन जातः सुमहांधकारः।। (Shiva Purana)
>  When Shiva's eyes were closed, Maha Andhakara (a great darkness) spread immediately. 
> संवृताभ्यां तु नेत्राभ्यां तमोभूतमचेतनम् | (Mahabharata)
>  As soon as Mahadeva's eyes were thus covered, all the regions became dark 
> अन्धकारोऽभवत्तत्र चिरकालं भयंकरः ।। (Skandha Purana)
>   there appeared a terrible darkness of a very long duration.
>  तमसा पूरितं विश्वमपारेण समन्ततः ।। (Skandha Purana)
>  The universe was filled all over with boundless darkness. 
> नापि जीवाः समभवन्नव्यक्तं केवलं स्थितम् ।। (Skandha Purana)
>  No living beings existed. Only the Unmanifest (Avyakta) remained by itself.

#### - The Third Eye:

> तृतीयं चास्य सम्भूतं नेत्रमादित्यसंनिभम् | (Mahabharata)
>  A third eye, resembling another sun, appeared (on forehead) 
> तृतीयं लोचनं दीप्तं सृष्टं ते रक्षता प्रजाः || (Mahabharata)
>   I created the third eye desirous of protecting all creatures. 
> शंभोर्ललाटे क्षणवह्नितप्तो विनिर्गतो भूरिजलस्य बिन्दुः।। (Shiva Purana)
>  rapturous rutting juice exuded from her hands became hot by the fire of the eye on his forehead 
> चन्द्रादित्याग्निरूपेण पिहितेष्वक्षिषु क्रमात् ।। (Skandha Purana)
>   When the eyes in the forms of the moon, the sun and the fire respectively were closed

#### - The Time Dilation:

> निर्होमं निर्वषट्कारं तत्सदः सहसाभवत् || (Mahabharata)
>  The Homa rites ceased. The universe became suddenly deprived of the sacred Vashat also. 
> निमिषार्द्धेन देवस्य जग्मुर्वत्सरकोटयः ।। (Skandha Purana)
>  In half Nimisha (0.1 seconds) Crores of Samvatsara (years) passed in the world 
> उक्तं त्वन्निमिषार्द्धेन जग्मुर्वत्सरकोटयः ।। (Skandha Purana)
>  Along with your half winking (ardha nimisha) crores of years have passed in the world. 
> भवतो निमिषार्द्धेन तेजसामुपसंहृतेः ।। गतान्यनेकवर्षाणि जगतां नाशहेतवे ।। (Skandha Purana)
>  Due to the withdrawal of lights for the duration of half a winking of yours, innumerable years of the worlds have gone by causing their destruction.