# Why is god Śiva called Mīḍhúṣṭama (मीढुष्टम)? Is there any specific story?

Tags: shiva, name, rudra

It is well known that god Śiva is called Āśutoṣa (आशुतोष) - the one who is easily pleased or appeased.

Recently, I came across another epithet for Śiva - Mīḍhúṣṭama (मीढुष्टम) while going through Kāraṇāgama (कारणागम), one of the 28 Śaivāgamas.

The great goddess (Pārvatī) refers to Śiva by this name as -

> [Chapter 2](https://archive.org/details/karan-agama-by-r.-m.-prabhulinga-shastri-shaiva-bharati-varanasi/page/n45/mode/1up?view=theater)
>
> ममापराधः क्षन्तव्यो **मीढुष्टम** नमोऽस्तु ते । त्वयि प्रसन्न जगति
> दुर्लभं किमु विद्यते ।।२५।।
>
> > Forgive my transgressions. **Ah Meedhustam - Shiva (Meedhustam is a
> > name of Shiva),** I pay salutation to you. If you please, what is not
> > found in the world. (25)

On searching the meaning, it was found to be -

> [Mīḍhúṣṭama](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/mIDhuSTama?q=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A2%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%AE) = "the most bounteous or liberal Lord"

This epithet is similar to Āśutoṣa in some ways.

Personally, the name sounds very unique.

#### Some of the occurrence of this name (Mīḍhúṣṭama) I could find in the Purāṇas are:-

- ### Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam Purāṇa

> [ŚB 4.7.6](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/7/6/?query=M%C4%AB%E1%B8%8Dh%C3%BA%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%ADama#bb28831)
>
> तदा सर्वाणि भूतानि श्रुत्वा **मीढुष्टमोदितम्** ॥ ६.अ॥
>
> > [6.](https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n463/mode/2up) O Vidura! When all beings heard the speech of **'the most bountiful (Mīḍhúṣṭama)'** god Siva, their hearts were fully satisfied, and they exclaimed - "Well done! Well done!".

- ### Śiva Purāṇa

> [ŚhP 2.2.41.26](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc389016.html)
>
> **मीढुष्टमाय** देवाय शिपिविष्टाय ते नमः ॥ २६.अ॥
>
> [26.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226061.html) Obeisance to **the most bounteous lord** who is pervaded by rays...

- ### Skanda Purāṇa

> [SkP 4.1.25.16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/skanda-purana-sanskrit/d/doc769123.html)
>
> **मीढुष्ट**मायोत्तरमीढुषे नमो नमो गणानां पतये गणाय ।
>
> > [16.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423763.html) **Obeisance to Mīḍhuṣṭama (‘the most excellent one among those who bestow desired fruits’)**...

- ### Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa:

The  Lalitopākhyāna (Lalitā-Māhātmya) from the Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa altogether refers Mīḍhúṣṭama as one of the names of a Rudra.

> [Chapter 34](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lalitopakhyana-lalita-mahatmya/d/doc362975.html)
>
> कुलालश्चेति रुद्रास्ते नवमावृतिदेवताः ॥ ३,३४.२५. अ॥
>  गिरिशः
> शिपिविष्टश्च कुंभज । मीढुष्टम इति प्रोक्ता रुद्रा दशमशालगाः ॥ [३,३४.२८](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A9%E0%A5%AA)
> ॥
>
> > 25. to 28. **The following are the Rudras in the tenth outer
> >     covering**,
> >     .. 
> >     Giriśa, Śipiviṣṭa, and **Mīḍhuṣṭama**.

---

### Questions:

- ##### 1. Is there any specific story as to why Śiva is also called Mīḍhúṣṭama (मीढुष्टम)?
- ##### 2. What information is available about the Rudra named - Mīḍhúṣṭama?

Comment: In rudram as well, in the 1st (1.13) Anuvakam, 5th (5.1) Anuvakam and later in 10th Anuvakam (10.10).

Answer (score 10):

Vedas also call Lord Shiva by the name "Midhustama". Sri Rudram of YajurVeda 5th Anuvaka states:

> नमो गिरिशाय च शिपिविष्टाय च । नमो **मीढुष्टमाय** ... (Yajurveda 4.5) 
> Salutations to Girisha, Shipivishta, **Midhustama**

He is the giver of many things and thus the name "Midhustama" is given to Parameswara.

Lord Kartikeya in his Sri Rudram Bhasya (in Shiva Rahasya) says that Parameswara is called Midhustama because he gave his seed to form Hiranyagarbha and thus as the originator of Brahma.

> रेतसः सेक्त्रे दिव्यहिरण्मयस्य च हरेर्गर्भे विधात्रे विधे:।। 
> who gave his Hiranyaretas (divine seed) in the womb of Hari and created Vidhata (Brahma)

This story is also cited by Linga Purana while mentioning why Lord is called [Pushtivardanam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/i-want-to-know-the-exact-explanation-of-maha-mrityunjaya-mantra/18185?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C11.1347#18185).

Abhinava Shankara in his commentary says three consecutive names Girisha (representing Lord Shiva), Shipivista (representing Lord Vishnu), and Midhustama (representing Lord Brahma) show that Parameswara is Trimurti Swarupadhari.

> अथ द्वाभ्यां त्रिमूर्त्यात्मकत्वम्, विश्वाधिकत्वं च दर्शयति-.... मीढुष्टम: अतिशयेन वीर्यसेचकः जगत्स्रष्टा हिरण्यगर्भः। 
> Now here are (names) which show Parameswara is Atman of Trimurti also. Vishwadhikatwa of Parameswara is seen here....  Midhustama: who by his potency, in the form of world creator Hiranyagarbha.

Sayana says he is called Midhustama because he is in the form of rain-giving clouds. Sayana in his commentary of above Sri Rudram says:

> मेघरुपेणात्यन्तं वर्षयिता मीढुष्टम: । 
> He is Midhustama because he is in the form of rain giving clouds.

It is well known that Parjanya is a form of Lord Shiva in his [Ashtamurti Swarupa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21725/what-are-the-eight-forms-ashtamurti-of-lord-shiva/21728?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C12.9388#21728). So it is no wonder that he is the giver of rain. By giver of rains giver of fruits of Yajna and Karma is also automatically understood as rainfall is symbolically taken as Yajna fruit also.

Similarly, RigVeda calls Lord Shiva as the giver of many things as [discussed here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/how-is-lord-shiva-revealed-in-the-rig-veda/17950#17950):

> भूरेर् दातारं (RigVeda 2.33.12)...मृत्योर्मुक्षीय मामृतात् (RigVeda 7.59.12)... वार्याणी शर्म वर्म छर्दिर (RigVeda 1.114.5)... हस्ते विभ्रद् भेषजा (RigVeda 1.114.5) 
> The giver of many.... who provides immortality through Moksha... grant us refugee, protection and shelter... whose hand filled with sovran medicines.

In the Yajurveda also after Rudra Namakam is recited, Rudra Chamakam is then recited which asks more than 300 things from Parameswara. In the Itihasas, Puranas, and Smritis also lord Shiva is well known as boon-giving Lord. Thus the name Midhustama which is given by Shruti is also explained through those boons also. Regarding the Rudra named "Midhustama", Lalitopakhyana says those Rudra forming Avarana of some Yantric arrangement and as the region of Rudra. It is extremely difficult to find out what the exact characters of those Rudras are. Only Sri Vidya Sadhakas may have some detailed information regarding it. It is very difficult to get more information regarding the popular Ekadash Rudras also. I'll further update the answer if I get some information on it.

Comment: Well! As usual, Tezz gives a fairly detailed and well-referenced answer.:) And, since you don't know about the second part of the question, I shouldn't expect maximum users here to know the answer either ;). In any case, I'll wait for Q (2), if in case.. ;) Thanks, you answered almost everything though!

Comment: It's a very beautiful and satisfying answer. Could you please give me a copy from where I can get the English translated version of Sri Abhinava Shankara Rudram bhashya!?. It would be of great help Tezz.