# Colour of Gods and Godesses

Tags: philosophy

The Hindu Mythological literature speaks that the color of Lord Brahma is red, the color of Lord Vishnu is blue (black in kaliyuga) while the color of Lord Shiva is white. The color of Goddess Mahakali (Consort of Lord Shiva)  is black, the color of Goddess Lakshmi (Consort of Lord Vishnu) is red while the color of Goddess Saraswati (Consort of Lord Brahma) is white. What is the secret of the colors and what is the secret of this combination?

Comment: Regarding colour of Lord Shiva, I have answered it [here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/why-are-hindu-gods-colored/18558#18558)