# Does Manu Smriti mention Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, manu-smriti

In Manusmriti, Brahma and Narayana are mentioned. But i didn't found mention of Lord Shiva. Is he also mentioned there?

Comment: I have a related question. Manu is said to be Manasika-Putra of Brahma. Shiva is said to be born out of Brahma's Krodha from his forehead. Is it possible Manu was born before Shiva ?

Comment: @ram no sir atleast according to shiv puran it is not. Also i dont think so that this is mentioned in any other purans as well. Well, with respect to shiv puran, brahma dev does tapasya to sadashiv for guiding him in activity of creation. And after that by his boon, rudra comes out of his ajna. So, by this we can see that the creation was yet to happen. And after this incident only, brahma dev creates his manas putras

Comment: yeah, different puranas have different versions of who is ultimate brahmam. Either all of them are wrong, or only one of them is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer [1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11638/19211) prooves that Rudra and Shiva are same. Hence I am quoting mention of Lord Rudra in Manu Smriti

> They call the Fathers “Vasus;” the grandfathers they call
> “**Rudras**,” and the great-grandfathers they call “ādityas” such is
> the ancient text.(Manu 3.284)
>
> The **Rudras**, Ādityas and the Maruts, along with the Great Sages,
> have performed this penance, for deliverance from all evils.(Manu
> 11.221)
>
> But he who has committed many sins becomes pure if he recites during a
> month the four verses addressed to Soma and **Rudra** and three verses
> begenning 'Aryaman, Varuna and Mitra' while he bathes in a river.
> (Manu 9.255)

Comment: Sir, rudras and rudra are different. Rudras are millions. While lord shiva is rudra. But here the rudras is referred to those multiple rudras.

Comment: Ok sir, I will delete first 2 , what about last verse @Rudra

Comment: Yes sir, i am also thinking about that. Thanks

Comment: Your most welcome sir @Rudra