# Do some Shaiva sects think that Rudra is different from Shiva?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, rudra

I have heard from some Shaivas that Shiva is another being from Rudra. They say that Rudra is tamasic whereas Shiva is sattvic.

Is this really what some Shaiva scriptures say?

Comment: See this answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/who-is-rudra-deva/9923#9923

Answer (score 1):

All Shaivas agree that Rudra is different from Shiva, AND Rudra is actually Saatvik while  Vishnu is Taamsi. Shiva is the lord of all gunas and the whole universe. This is explained by Brahmaji himself in Chapter Sixteen: Description of creation in Rudra Samhita Section One of Shiva MahaPuraan:

> Vishnu, Rudra and I (Brahma) represent the Gunas.

> **Siva is free from Gunas. He is the Supreme** Brahman, the undecaying.

> Vishnu is of Sattva attribute, I (Brahma) am of Rajas attribute and Rudra is of Tamas attribute. **This is only in the view of activities in this world. But in fact in name it is otherwise.**

> **Vishnu is Taamasik nature within ... Rudra is of Saattvika nature within... Sati is of Saattvika nature; Lakshmi is of Taamasika nature;**

> The great Goddess Sivaa is of three natures.

Comment: Rudra is sattvic? In another comment you said, "Vishnu is 100% TAMASIC and comparable to Rudra, not Shiva (who is above all gunas)." When you said, "comparable to Vishnu and not Shiva", I thought you were indicating that Rudra is also tamasic.