# Meaning of a sentence in Sri Rudram Namakam

Tags: shiva, meaning, rudram

नमः सोमाय च रुद्राय च नमस्ताम्राय चारुणाय च

What I found on other sites is this...

Salutations to Him who is with His consort Uma.
Salutations to Him who is red and rosy-red also.

My questions are...

- सोमा from my understanding means Moon. According to a [Wikipedia link](https://(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soma_(drink)))

> In the Vedic tradition, soma (Sanskrit: सोम) is a ritual drink of
> importance among the early Vedic Indo-Aryans. The Rigveda mentions it,
> particularly in the Soma Mandala. Gita mentions the drink in Chapter
> 9. It is equivalent to the Iranian haoma.

What does सोमा mean in this context?

- And, रुद्रा means the fierce one, or the violent and furious form.

I am wondering, in this context what does the above line in Rudram mean.

Thank you

Comment: see this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50582/why-is-lord-shiva-called-soma and this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17091/why-8th-anuvaka-of-sri-rudram-is-special-and-what-are-benefits-of-chanting-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you that was wealth of information 